# Installing Portainer Agent on debian results in Failure Read Only FileSystem

Tags: docker, portainer

I've installed docker using the instructions here : https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

and I've used the instructions in portainer to deploy a portainer agent, the instructions that were provided was :

> docker run -d \   -p 9001:9001 \   --name portainer_agent \
> --restart=always \   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \   -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes \   portainer/agent:2.18.3

I've verified that the container for the agent is running used sudo docker ps and it is running.

However, in portainer when I try to connect to the agent I am receiving an error "Failure read-only only filesystem" I've tried to interpret some other threads on forums related to this - however, the solutions suggested on there hasn't appeared to work.

I've checked /var/lib/docker/volumes, it currently has the following files :

> brw------- 1 root root 254, 2 Nov 28 12:00 backingFsBlockDev
> -rw------- 1 root root  32768 Nov 28 12:00 metadata.db

I'm assuming that there are no issues with this since it is root. What does the Read only filesystem mean and how can I resolve this ?